# Can you tell me where the configuration error is in a nginx.conf file?

Tags: nginx, debian, webserver

### Premise · What I want to realize

I'm trying to build a web server with nginx and I've gotten an error of nginx. but I can't find the error.

### Web server's environment

- based on a Google Cloud Compute Engine
- debian 12.8
- nginx 1.24.0

### What I did

**1. Add some cofig for booting php-fpm**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    #ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    charset UTF-8;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

### Problems occurring · Error messages

```
~$ sudo service nginx status
× nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-03-12 00:54:31 UTC; 4s ago
   Duration: 21min 29.633s
       Docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/
    Process: 34119 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 7ms

Mar 12 00:54:31 instance-20240306-133649 systemd[1]: Starting nginx.service - nginx - high performance web ser>
Mar 12 00:54:31 instance-20240306-133649 nginx[34119]: nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here i>
Mar 12 00:54:31 instance-20240306-133649 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, statu>
Mar 12 00:54:31 instance-**** systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 12 00:54:31 instance-**** systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx.service - nginx - high performance

$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I got the errors. What shoud I do?
Could you lend me a hand? Thank you for your reading.

Comment: You have placed the `server` block above the `http` block. The `server` block needs to be **inside** the `http` block.